# Gram Matrix with another inner product

Tags: matrices, hilbert-spaces

Let $H\subset L^2(\Omega)$ a finite dimentional space with inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)_{0,\Omega}$ and $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^n\subset H$ a basis of $H$.

Is the Gram Matrix $G(v_1,\ldots,v_n)=((v_i,v_j)_{0,\Omega})_{i,j=1,\ldots,n}$ a non singular matrix?

If the inner product into the Gram Matrix was $(\cdot,\cdot)_H$ is clear that $G$ is a non singular matrix because $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^n$ is l.i. I think that in case we have the same result, but i don't know a way of prove this.

Comment: $G$ is the matrix of the inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)_{0,\Omega}$ with respect to the basis $\{v_i\}$. Hence it is positive definite. Hence nonsingular.

Comment: Don't we have for $\alpha \in \mathbb R^n, \alpha^\top G \alpha = \Vert \alpha^\top v \Vert^2_{0,\Omega}$?

Comment: what is $v$ in your expression Roger?

Comment: I get the idea... if $\{v_i\}$ is basis of $H$, then it's a lineary independent set of $L^2(\Omega)$. Then $G$ is not singular.

Comment: $v=(v_1,...,v_n)^\top$